# $a=b \implies b=0$ puzzle. What is wrong?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-verification, proof-explanation, puzzle

I found the below online with no explanation what is wrong, but I am guessing it must be a condition or assumption, but can't see what the issue is.

```
a = b
ab = b²
ab - a² = b² - a²
a(b - a) = (b + a)(b - a)
a = b + a
0 = b
```

Can anyone see what the issue is?

Comment: Hint:  check for where you divided by $0$.

Comment: Stare at $(b-a)$ and ponder what happens when you divide both sides by it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot cancel $b-a$ like that since you have started with $a=b$ and hence $b-a =0$.

Answer (score 2):

Division is only valid when you are not dividing by $0$. You divide by $b-a$, which is equal to $0$ since $a=b$

Answer (score 1):

The way to disprove basically any of this kind of puzzle is to step through it with actual numbers. Where does it first go wrong?

Let $b=a=1$. Then:

- $1=1$
- $1\times 1 = 1^2$
- $1 \times 1 - 1^2 = 1^2 - 1^2$
- $1 (1-1) = (1+1)(1-1)$
- $1 = 1+1$ (wait, what?)
- $0=1$ (abort! abort!)

Answer (score 0):

In the 4'th line you canceled out $(b-a)$. This $(b-a)$ term can be canceled out only when $(b-a)\neq0$, but according to your first assumption: $(a=b)\Rightarrow(b-a)=0$, so according to your assumption you can't cancel out $(b-a)$ like this.